# how to display calculation of checkboxes between span tag

Tags: jquery

I now have this piece of javascript for a calculation which works great.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".checkboxes").click(
    function () {
        var ntot = 0;
        $(".checkboxes:checked").each(function () {
            ntot += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $(".totaalprijs").val(ntot);
    })
    .change();
});
```

The form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                Check this for 10% savings
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="10" />
                <br />
                Check this for 15% savings
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="15" />
                <br />
                Check this for 20% savings
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="20" />
                <br />

            </form>

                <input type="text" class="totalprice"  size="5" />
```

The output is being displayed in the last input with class="totalprice"

How can i make this work in a span tag with class="totalprice" ?

So this:

```
     <input type="text" class="totalprice"  size="5" />
```

should be replaced with this:

```
<span class="totalprice"><!-- output value should be here--></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`

```
$(".totalprice").text(ntot);
```

Comment: ist actually not the failure :) you just had a typo ^^

Comment: Additional Explanation: `.val()` sets the tag's `value` attrubute, so it would be `<span class="..." value="...">`. `.text()` sets the inner text of the `<span>`, so `<span class="...">Text</span>`.

Answer (score -1):

you simply have a typo

your js is

```
$(".totaalprijs").val(ntot);
```

your input is

```
<input type="text" class="totalprice"  size="5" />
```

`totaalprijs` is not `totalprice`.

so just correct the typo and you good :)

also if you want to display in span you can use `.text()` and `.html()`

Comment: though you are correct, I think this is not the problem. I guess it's just a c&p error. The problem is val not working on spans.

Comment: @Christoph if he copy & paste than he has this typo for sure ^^

Comment: Oops...i see, but still doesn't work with val() but now DOES work with text()

Comment: No need to be nitpicky, it's a simple conversion error. You apparently didn't read the question thoroughly enough :-p

Comment: Im not sure what you mean with "didnt read the question" when you see my post you will see i did.... but...what ever. Ops question is solved and its good. So no need to talk about this anymore ;)